# Lemma regarding subgroup of group of automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G\subset \operatorname{Aut}(A)$ and $G$ be a subgroup.
>
> Then $|G|<\infty \implies A $ is integral over $A^G$ where
>
> $A^G:=\{a\in A: \sigma (a)=a ~~ \forall \sigma \in G$}

My book's proof is the following:

Consider polynomial $P(x):=\Pi_{\sigma \in G} (x-\sigma(a))$ and the result follows.

I don't understand why the result follows from it. Any explanation please? I'm algebra noob.

Edit: $A$ is commutative $k$-domain.

Book: Introduction to Commutative Algebra. M.F.Atiyah, I.G.Macdonald
Addison-Wesley Publishing 1969.

Comment: And what book ?

Comment: edited 1st post,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for any element $a$ of $A$, it is a root of the polynomial $P(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\sigma(a))$. This is actually an integral polynomial over $A^G$ since you have for any $\tau\in G$, $\tau P(x) = \prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\tau\sigma(a)) = \prod_{\sigma\in G}(x-\sigma(a))$ (note that the action of $\tau$ actually permute those $\sigma$).

Comment: Could you explain what is $\tau P(x)$? It's not intuitive to me at all...Thanks

Comment: The automorphism $\tau$ is applied to the coefficients of $P(x)$: If $P(x) = a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0$, then $\tau P(x) = \tau(a_n) x^n + \cdots + \tau(a_0)$. Since $\tau$ extends to a ring homomorphism from $A[x]$ to $A[x]$, we can apply $\tau$ to each factor in the product representation. The point is that $\tau P(x) = P(x)$ implies $\tau(a_i) = a_i$ for any coefficient $a_i$ of $P(x)$. Since this holds for all $\tau \in G$, the coefficients of $P(x)$ are in $A^G$.